# External Script Not Working with HTML form

Tags: javascript

I have an external JS file that converts 2 values and a HTML form which converts the values in the fields automatically, but when the code is in the external file, it doesn't work. When the code is directly pasted on the site, it works.

Is there a work around to make this work? I want this and another external js file to stay external to keep the site tidy.

https://jsfiddle.net/cwqb1kgt/

```
  <script>
    function convert(source) {
      const kJInput = document.getElementById('kJ');
      const calInput = document.getElementById('cal');
      const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

      const kJValue = parseFloat(kJInput.value);
      const calValue = parseFloat(calInput.value);

      if (source === 'kJ' && !isNaN(kJValue)) {
        // Convert kJ to cal (1 kJ â‰ˆ 0.239 kcal)
        const convertedValue = kJValue * 0.239;
        calInput.value = convertedValue.toFixed(2);
        resultDiv.innerHTML = '';
      } else if (source === 'cal' && !isNaN(calValue)) {
        // Convert cal to kJ (1 kcal â‰ˆ 4.184 kJ)
        const convertedValue = calValue / 4.184;
        kJInput.value = convertedValue.toFixed(2);
        resultDiv.innerHTML = '';
      } else {
        // Handle invalid input
        resultDiv.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid number.';
      }
    }
  </script>
```

This is the errror:
Uncaught ReferenceError: convert is not defined"

Comment: Does this happen in an HTML page?  Or only in JSFiddle?  Also, are those `<script>` tags in your actual JavaScript file?  Because that's not JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the JS in the JS section. In the JS section of jsfiddle add the JS code that you wish to link or use. It will work.

[Where the JS section is in jsfiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkJWI.png)

Comment: I'd originally thought that too, but look at the "Resources" option on the left side of the screen.  I *suspect* the problem is that the external JS file contains HTML code, and that this is merely a typo in that regard.